# why we use RMSE rather than average residual as the assessment criteria of model?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

Usually, we use **RMSE** to assess the performance of a model. I am curious about why we use the average residual to replace the RMSE ?

the definition of **RMSE** : [image: RMSE]

the **average residual** mentioned here is : [image]

for example:

we have three samples: 0 1 2

the prediction values of these samples are : 0 2 10

so the average residual is [image]

the RMSE is [image]

so what's the difference between these two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I will refer to RMSE and "average residual" as **loss functions**)

1. Notice that the expression you give for "average residual" can have positive, zero *and negative* values, and it is *not bounded from bellow*. This is not a good property of a loss function, which should have a lower bound (usually zero) which corresponds to its optimum. If you try to minimize this function, you are actually training your model to make as large an underestimation as possible (you're training your predictions to be as small and negative as possible so that the loss function will be small). In your example, prediction values of -1000, -1000, -1000 would yield an excellent (i.e small) value of the loss function, even though the predictions are very wrong.  Also, you may get a loss value of zero even though you have huge errors, due to errors averaging to zero.
2. Maybe you were thinking of using absolute value in the "average residual" function (for each term in the sum). This is actually a loss function that can be used, and is called **L1 loss** but it has at least the following two disadvantages:
   **A)** It has less nice analytical properties. For example, when using the linear model for regression, the RMSE criterion is exactly solvable (i.e there is a simple formula for the model parameters which minimize the loss), but the L1 loss is not.
   **B)** The gradient is piece-wise constant (think of the derivative of the absolute value function). This means that if you perform the optimization using gradient-based methods, then parameter values near the optimum get the same gradient as values farther away from the optimum, and not as you would expect, that large errors will get larger corrections.

Comment: yeah, the average residual should use absolute value. thanks for your answer, I got it ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The RMSE, besides being a convex function, ties well with Gaussian Distribution as RMSE has a similar expression as the standard deviation of a Normal.

Normal distribution is very well studied and occurs naturally in various stochastic processes found across natural sciences. Equating error to the spread of the Normal distribution is helpful in a lot of cases e.g. log-likelihood (https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/normal-distribution-maximum-likelihood), log-posterior (http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/sta4273/notes/Lecture2.pdf look at evidence approximation slide)  optimization etc.